# "Cannot find module 'custom-module' or its corresponding type declarations" for module added from GitHub

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github, node-modules, package.json

I used `yarn add github:username/custom-module` to add a custom module to my project. The module and its contents appears in my `node_modules` folder, but I'm unable to import anything from it.

I import it into my file like using `import { Component } from "custom-module";`, but TypeScript returns, "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'custom-module' in 'filepath...'".

My project's `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^4.0.2",
    "@dnd-kit/sortable": "^5.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.176",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "@types/ws": "^8.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mobx": "^6.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-quick-reactions": "github:username/custom-module",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "ws": "^8.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "serve": "node -r esm src/backend/server.ts"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0"
  }
}
```

And the `package.json` from the module:

```
{
  "name": "custom-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "description": "A description.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "react-component",
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/username/custom-module#readme",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/username/custom-module/issues"
  },
  "repository": "github:username/custom-module",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the folder name in `node_modules`? Is it `custom-module` or something else?

Comment: The folder name is `custom-module`.

Comment: Doesn't look like that `custom-module` has a `main`, `files` or `directories` section so you might need to directly link to a module within the `custom-module` directory structure, eg `custom-module/dist/foobar`. I'm just guessing here since you haven't included enough information to debug.

Comment: Thank, you @Phil . That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phil suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136091/cannot-find-module-custom-module-or-its-corresponding-type-declarations-for?noredirect=1#comment125747716_71136091), the `custom-module` `package.json` did not contain `main`, `files`, or `directories`. I had to import directly from `"custom-module/file/path/Component"`.